# Faster charge through higher amp charger?

Tags: charging

I'm looking for a solution to charge my Android smarpthone as fast as possible when travelling, eg. when sleeping at a camp site where I don't want to have to sit there for two hours just to make sure the phone doesn't get stolen.

Most USB chargers are 1 amp, but I was wondering if I could use a higher amp charger, eg. 2-5 amps, so the phone would charge faster without getting fried?

Thank you.

Comment: Depends on the phone. There are some standards but they are mostly incompatible with one another. Like Qualcomm's Quick Charge and Samsung's Adaptive Quick Charge and Qi quick charging. Most of them do either 5V 2A (10W) or even 9V 1.67A (Samsung Adaptive Fast Charge, 15W). Find what works for you, but most of them will just be fine with 5V 2A regardless of standard.

Comment: Can I use much higher amps, eg. 2-5A, without frying the phone?

Comment: No, you'll most likely just fry the board or cause over-current and make the battery explode. Your cable, connector and everything connected to it will suffer damage, too. 2A is the usual fast charging current. Any more requires special circuits to handle more current.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try with a 2A charger and see how it goes. Thank you.

Comment: Also: Make sure you use a proper charger to allow the phone and the charger to negotiate the current. If not, you might risk permanent damage on any of the connected devices (so use a quality charger and no $1 china ripoff).

Comment: "So, in the end, there are three areas where USB charging can be adversely affected – the USB port standard used (SDP, CDP or DCP), electrical signature mismatching and the quality of the USB cable being used." http://apcmag.com/android-usb-charging-secrets.htm/